# Proper way of lazy-loading a single select box options via ajax once clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, webkit, onclick

I have a select box that should be populated only when clicked. The query involved takes a long time so I'm deattaching it from the standard data shown on the page.

I have implemented the function `loadMyData(element, id)` which does an ajax request and returns the data as JSON. Then it populates the select box.

the event is binded to the element as this:

```
<select onclick="loadMyData(this, 1)">
</select>
```

and the select box is populated as this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, optionData) {
  select.options[element.options.length] 
             = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
});
```

On Gecko-based browsers works, but on Webkit ones (safari and chrome), when I click the select box, an empty drop-down box is shown before the ajax request and after the response, the drop-down box is not refreshed. One have to click outside the select box and click it again in order to see the updated "options".

Is there any way to force it to refresh the contents? or to simply automatically select first one and hide the drop-down box?

**tried onfocus and found the same results. onmouseover works but is "not usable". onchange is not viable due select box is empty at its initial state.*

Comment: Have you considered using a synchronous request with this one? That may do away with any time lags and give the select box a chance to update properly! Also, why the onclick based loading? It is possible to perform the update based on a user's interaction with some other UI element prior to reaching the dropdown? If the select is not dependant on any other UI choices, why not populate it beforehand?

Comment: Or as an afterthought... why not fire the loading function on DOM Ready albeit in async mode? That way the initial page loads immediately without having to execute the long query and browser doesn't freeze up... and by the time the user is ready to play with the UI elements, the select box has been silently populated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Don't use standard html select boxes - your application doesn't degrade gracefully eitherway.
2. Use some clickjacking - have a transparent div OVER selet box - problems with IE
3. Use a checbox to allow "non standard" answer, which would populate the select box and make it clickable (not disabled)
4. My favourite: cache query results and populate the select box right away. Give another "referesh options" button near the select box to reload options thru AJAX.

Comment: I discard caching due it should display fresh data. I would go with the clickjacking hack but it feels like dirty so I guess I'm just going to use a standard button and replace it with the "fresh" select box once clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the bad browser here is IE 6 and below because it has this readonly thing on the select options so the only way to handle it is replacing the entire select.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>lazy loading thing</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>
                <span id="replaceMe"><select name="drinks">
                    <option>oh well... click me...</option>
                </select></span>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function() {
     $('#replaceMe').one('click', replaceIt);
});

function replaceIt(e) {
    $(this).html('now wait...');
    $.post('options.php', {}, replaceItHandler, 'json');
}

function replaceItHandler(options) {
    var select = '<select name="drinks">';
    $.each(options, function(i, option) {
        select += '<option value="' + option.data + '">' + option.label + '</option>';
    });
    select += '</select>';
    $('#replaceMe').html(select);
}
```

**options.php**

```
<?php
$options[] = array('data' => 0, 'label' => 'Water');
$options[] = array('data' => 0, 'label' => 'Wine');
$options[] = array('data' => 0, 'label' => 'Beer');
$options[] = array('data' => 0, 'label' => 'Coke');
echo json_encode($options);
?>
```

And obviusly you can use PHP or whatever and JSON like this or send the entire select, it's your choice.

Comment: Well it worked on ie8, the only browsers not working were webkit-based ones (chrome and safari). Replacing the whole select box is an idea but I rather show a button and on click it replace it with the select box. I didn't wanted to use extra html elements in order to load the contents of the select box but I guess there is no other way while using standard html select box.

Comment: is working in my Google Chrome (1.0.154.65) and even in Opera (
9.64), I just tested a minute ago.

Answer (score 0):

On Safari the problem is the onclick event it should be onchange.

see here the solution: http://munteanutraian.info/forum/?p=5